# How to open UserControl from another UserControl in Form panel

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, user-controls

I've met a problem.

I am working on C# Form application and I need to switch between UserControls in panel which is located in my main Form via button.

If I set 2 buttons in main Form I can easy switch with show/hide methods but if the button is located in one of the UserControl1 I can do hide method but I have no idea how to show the UserControl2 in the same panel.

```
namespace GameTests
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!panel1.Controls.Contains(uc1.Instance))
        {
            panel1.Controls.Add(uc1.Instance);
            uc1.Instance.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            uc1.Instance.BringToFront();
        }
        else
            uc1.Instance.BringToFront();
    }
}}


namespace GameTests
{
public partial class uc1 : UserControl
{
    private static uc1 instance;

    public static uc1 Instance
    {
            get
        {
            if(instance == null)
            {
                instance = new uc1();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }

    public uc1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
    }
}}
```

I need the show option for UserControl2 with name uc2 in button1_Click method in uc1 class

Comment: Create an event in `UserContro1` and raise it when the user clicks on a button in user control 1. Subscribe for event in you your form and show an instance of `UserControl2`.

Comment: Any examples on MSDN or anywhere else?

Comment: Yes, see the duplicate post.